Blogdown starting error and rmd render not working
I'm strugling to get blogdown with initial hugo theme working out of box.
I have the following error when a new blogdown project with RStudio is created:
Error in parse(n = -1, file = file, srcfile = NULL, keep.source = FALSE) :  4:0: unexpected end of input 2:   shrtcts::add_rstudio_shortcuts(set_keyboard_shortcuts = TRUE) 3:  ^


Everything is up to date:
R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Fedora Linux 39 (Workstation Edition), RStudio 2023.12.1.402

Locale:
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NAME=C
LC_ADDRESS=C LC_TELEPHONE=C
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

Package version:
base64enc_0.1.3 blogdown_1.19 bookdown_0.39 bslib_0.7.0
cachem_1.0.8 cli_3.6.2 digest_0.6.35 evaluate_0.23
fastmap_1.1.1 fontawesome_0.5.2 fs_1.6.3 glue_1.7.0
graphics_4.3.3 grDevices_4.3.3 highr_0.10 htmltools_0.5.8.1
httpuv_1.6.15 jquerylib_0.1.4 jsonlite_1.8.8 knitr_1.46
later_1.3.2 lifecycle_1.0.4 magrittr_2.0.3 memoise_2.0.1
methods_4.3.3 mime_0.12 promises_1.3.0 R6_2.5.1
rappdirs_0.3.3 Rcpp_1.0.12 rlang_1.1.3 rmarkdown_2.26
sass_0.4.9 servr_0.30 stats_4.3.3 tinytex_0.50
tools_4.3.3 utils_4.3.3 xfun_0.43 yaml_2.3.8

Hugo version: 0.125.1


rmd files render without any issue with other project. Only blogdown causes this type of error.
I tried to create a blogdown project with RStudio and have the mentioned error.

I found the solution to my problem. By deleting the .RProfile file, the problem was completely solved.
It took me more than a day to figure it out.
